# Increased size of combined MP4 compared to its source MP4s and MP3

Tags: mp3, mp4, video-editing

I combined 7 MP4 files **(278MB size)** and overlaid it with One MP3 file **(6.25MB size)**. The resulting MP4 file's has drastically increased to **543MB**. Can't understand the reasons.

**Software used** - Wondershare Filmora

**Resolutions:**
All 7 MP4 files - 1920 x 1080
Resulting MP4 file - 1920 x 1080 (i.e. same)

Can anyone apprise?

Answer (score 0):

> Resolutions: All 7 MP4 files - 1920 x 1080 Resulting MP4 file - 1920 x 1080 (i.e. same)

The resolution isn't relevant, but the bitrate is.  Your software is re-encoding the video, and doing so at a higher bitrate.

Try something like FFmpeg instead, and use `-vcodec copy` to avoid re-encoding.